# Make install PHP 7.4.9 with Ubuntu 12.04 Error

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, php-7.4, make-install

#### Downlaod PHP 7.4.9 source from php.net.

#### ./configure

```
./configure --prefix=/opt/php74 --with-config-file-path=/opt/php74/etc --sysconfdir=/opt/php74/etc --with-config-file-scan-dir=/opt/php74/etc/conf.d --with-icu-dir=/usr/local/icu --enable-bcmath --enable-calendar --enable-dba --enable-exif --enable-ftp --enable-fpm --enable-gd --enable-intl --enable-mbstring --enable-mysqlnd --enable-pcntl --enable-phpdbg --enable-phpdbg-readline --enable-phpdbg-webhelper --enable-shmop --enable-soap --enable-sockets --enable-sysvmsg --enable-sysvsem --enable-sysvshm --with-curl --with-ffi --with-libxml --with-libedit --with-mysql-sock=/tmp/mysql.sock --with-mysqli=mysqlnd --with-openssl --with-pdo-mysql=mysqlnd --with-sodium --with-xsl --with-zip --with-zlib --enable-mbregex
```

#### Print this:

```
checking for icu-uc >= 50.1 icu-io icu-i18n... no
configure: error: Package requirements (icu-uc >= 50.1 icu-io icu-i18n) were not met:

No package 'icu-uc' found
No package 'icu-io' found
No package 'icu-i18n' found

Consider adjusting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable if you
installed software in a non-standard prefix.

Alternatively, you may set the environment variables ICU_CFLAGS
and ICU_LIBS to avoid the need to call pkg-config.
See the pkg-config man page for more details.
```

#### I installed icu from source in */usr/local/icu*, like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dtIfv.png)

Comment: Did you try doing what the message suggests? See https://askubuntu.com/questions/210210/pkg-config-path-environment-variable

Comment: OK, I will try it with tiis tip.